# Kafka consumer in auto commit false is throwing exception while acknowledge for the asyc call "KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access"

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are making the  kafka auto commit to false for Kafka Concurrent Consumer. Then  based on the another  Microservice call in Async using Rest Template it we are trying to acknowledge the response. We are getting error of KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access while acknowledgment.acknowledge(); is executing.

If we remove the async in the method it is not throwing the exception and working fine.

```
    @Async("******")
    public CompletableFuture<String> process*****Service(****** ******, String serviceUrl, Acknowledgment acknowledgment){

        ResponseEntity<String> serviceResponse = null;
        int retryCount = 0;
        String response = null;
        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = KafkaConsumerUtil.prepareHeaders(ApplicationConstant.****, apikey);
            HttpEntity<******> entity = new HttpEntity<>(*****, headers);
            retryCount++; 
            System.out.println("Attempting retry mechanism with counter "+retryCount);
            serviceResponse = restTemplate.exchange(serviceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
            if (null != serviceResponse) {
                response = serviceResponse.getStatusCode().toString();
                acknowledgment.acknowledge();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(ApplicationConstant.*****.concat("Exception caught at process*****Service "+e.getMessage()));
            String producerUrl = appProperties.getKafkapropmap().get(ApplicationConstant.PUBLISHER_MS_SERVICE_URL);
//          deadLetterTopic.invokeDeadLetterTopic(****Request, producerUrl, acknowledgment);
        }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
    }



    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(concurrency));
        return factory;
    }

    and
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
```

Error

```
2019-10-17 11:59:03.612 [Pre-******-3] ERROR c.a.m.reg.service.******* -
                ********: Exception caught at ******Service KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
```

We are using spring-kafka 1.3.0.RELEASE

Any hints are appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should upgrade to the latest 1.3.x release (1.3.10).

With older versions, you can't use `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` with async acks; you can only use `AckMode.MANUAL`, which queues the ack for the main consumer thread which will do the commit.

The consumer is not thread safe.

`MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` could only be used when the ack is done by the thread that calls the listener. The container now detects which thread is doing the ack and will queue an async commit.

This was fixed in 1.3.4, but the latest version is 1.3.10.